# Searching VendorBill in netsuite using webservice

Tags: search, netsuite

I need to retrive bill information from netsuite. How to search the bill(VendorBill-complextype) using webservice. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a [blog post](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2011/06/sample-search-code/) that has an example of doing a Netsuite API search with 2011 and earlier versions of the API.  You should be able to just modify the code for the VendorBill complex type.